# Fixed navbar that disappears when not on top and not scrolling isn't working as intended

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a navbar that displays normally when `window.pageYOffset` is less than 500, otherwise it would show while scrolling and hide 1200 milliseconds after user stops scrolling. Here's my CodePen https://codepen.io/youssefwael/pen/LYZKmom and at the bottom of the js you'll see the part I'm stuck at

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    nav.style.display = "block";
    clearTimeout(hide);
    if (window.pageYOffset > 500) {
        const hide = setTimeout(() => {
            nav.style.display = "none";
        }, 1200);
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've been trying to figure this out since yesterday because I feel like it really should work. Currently if you scroll up and down quickly it bugs out the timeout. Also, scrolling from the bottom up quickly causes the navbar to disappear at the top, which shouldn't happen. I thought adding the `clearTimeout()` would fix both of these, but it doesn't.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem so I'll post it here for future dwellers who may come across the same issue. All I had to do is declare `hide` outside the function and now it works wonders.

```
let hideNav;
document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    nav.style.display = "block";
    clearTimeout(hideNav);
    if (window.pageYOffset > 500) {
        hideNav = setTimeout(() => {
            nav.style.display = "none";
        }, 1200);
    }
});
```

PS: I don't know how to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

For the scroll behaviour I have made some changes in your event Listener
Here is a simplified version:

```
const myNavbar = document.querySelector(".navbar__menu");

document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 500) {
      myNavbar.classList.add("navbar-fixed");
      myNavbar.classList.remove("navbar-relative");
    }
  else if (window.pageYOffset < 500) {
      myNavbar.classList.add("navbar-relative");
    myNavbar.classList.remove("navbar-fixed");
    }
});
```

you can simply use styling relative or fixed on navbar based on these classes.
There is also a bug in your code because the hide variable is not accessible outside its scope

Comment: I like how this solution works, but it doesn't really achieve what I'm trying to do. My main issue is that I get very confused with how `clearTimeout()` works. Do you know how I could set it up correctly so that every time the function is triggered, it cancels the timeout set by the last time it was? I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Youssef I would love to help you with this but I am a bit busy, you can call a function on event related to scroll that will reset your timeout and another event that will sense that user is not scrolling and it will start timeout